# How to update a Azure resource tag value when there is a hyphen in its name?

Tags: powershell, azure, tags

I have written a PowerShell script to update the Tag values for specific tag names, now for all the tag names that do not have special characters in them (eg. department) this works just fine, but I have one tag name that has a hyphen in it (eg. "it-environment") and when I try to update this tag value with my script it does not work. Did anyone have a similar issue and maybe a solution for how to work around this problem?

thanks!

Edit: If the tag name is not present I can create it with my script and give it a value but when I try to update it (so the tag is already present) it does not work, which is weird because the other tags work as expected.

Final Edit: We did some research, turns out Update-AzTag can actually handle tags with special characters and even create them if they are not present all you have to do is enclose them in qoutes so for example: "it-environment", hope this might help someone who has the same issue in the future.

Comment: Surround it with single quotes? 'bored-admin-byte'

Comment: @Gantendo yes I use single quotes around the value so for example $tags['it-environment'] = $itenvironment ($itenvironment is my parameter)

Comment: Are we allowed to see this PowerHell script?

Comment: @Gantendo I added the Script with some changes (for business reasons)